# OS harddisk if installed on other machine, restarts

Tags: operating-system

I have installed Win7 on one machine. After some days, if I put that hard disk in another machine, it keeps restarting and does not boot up. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the hard drive have the Win7 installation on it? If so, it probably won't boot in another machine, as each installation is customized to whichever machine installed it. You will probably need to repair/re-install the OS to make it boot.